# How to display menu without pressing menu button?

Tags: android, menu, key, show

I have a menu that I want to appear on the screen when the app starts, without the user having to press the menu key.

What is a good way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Activity.openOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29) or [Activity.openContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openContextMenu%28android.view.View%29)?